Got error - failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found
Other similar posts did not fix this error.
Using Codeigniter and Openai API to generate images.
Started getting this error after server migration.
Now it just places 0 byte img file on the server and throws this error.
It was 3MB images before, not huge.
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: file_get_contents(https://oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/private/org-vsNFQNxeX6XH5mkcucSgjmwr/user-xrjvRzlnKwWRfjibOKWJRpd6/img-3VQ4qjdmWfizq6mWRGRl7TgI.png?st=2024-09-28T13%3A24%3A34Z&se=2024-09-28T15%3A24%3A34Z&sp=r&sv=2024-08-04&sr=b&rscd=inline&rsct=image/png&skoid=d505667d-d6c1-4a0a-bac7-5c84a87759f8&sktid=a48cca56-e6da-484e-a814-9c849652bcb3&skt=2024-09-28T00%3A48%3A37Z&ske=2024-09-29T00%3A48%3A37Z&sks=b&skv=2024-08-04&sig=6zC7Ix2wBA3L1Bn9OYW%2BeE%2BX5svP0AsRjm%2BTe%2BbobNo%3D): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found
Filename: controllers/Images.php
Line Number: 599
Backtrace:
File: /home/rztxdnnj/public_html/app/application/controllers/Images.php Line: 599 Function: file_get_contents
File: /home/rztxdnnj/public_html/app/index.php Line: 316 Function: require_once


Tryd the image link, its working
allow_url_fopen and file_get_contents are On
Images.php:
  public function ai_image_generator(){
        $keys_words = '';
        if(isset($_POST['key_words'])):
        $keys_words = html_escape($_POST['key_words']);
        endif;
        $image_size = '';
        if(isset($_POST['image_size'])):
        $image_size = html_escape($_POST['image_size']);
        endif;
        $ogj = str_replace(" ","%20",$keys_words);
        if(!empty($image_size)){
            $size = $image_size;
        }else{
            $size = "1024x1024";
        }
        if(!empty($ogj)){
            $args = array(
                "prompt" => $ogj,
                "n"=>1,
                "size"=>$size,
                'model'  => 'dall-e-3'
            );

        $data_string = json_encode($args);
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer '.AI_IMAGES_CODE
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
        $a = json_decode($result,true);
            if(isset($a['data'])){
                foreach($a['data'] as $a_child){
                    $image_path = 'openai_images'.rand(10,100);
                    $img = 'uploads/ai/'.$image_path.'.png';
                    $imgUrl = $a_child['url'];
                    file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($imgUrl));
                    $img_url= base_url().'/uploads/ai/'.$image_path.'.png';
                    echo '<div data-url="'.$img_url.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="AI IMAGES"></div>';
                }
            }else{
                echo '<p>'.esc_html($a['error']['message']).'</p>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<p>'.esc_html__('Please Enter Object Name.','gpt-blaster').'</p>';
        }


      die();
    }

I donot own the server, i am not sure what they did or did nothing at all to solve this. But what am sure off that allow_url_fopen and file_get_contents are On.

Note: HTTPS is only supported when the openssl extension is enabled.

This question is similar to: Unable to find the wrapper "https" with file_get_contents. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OpenSSL support  enabled
OpenSSL Library Version  OpenSSL 1.1.1w 11 Sep 2023
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.1.1w 11 Sep 2023
